# Why is filter function throwing array error?

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have example code provided with a plugin for Wordpress. The plugin pulls the image and caption from each new Instagram post into the WP blog as a new post. The trigger to check Instagram for a new post is fired when the site is visited.

Everything works well except this filter.

In this particular filter, I am taking the first hashtag from Instagram, inserting it in the categories list and assigning it to the new blog post as the category.

Here is my code, the error thrown is below the code:

```
add_filter( 'igp_image_post_taxonomy_terms', function ( $terms, $image, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
   $tags = isset( $image->tags ) ? maybe_unserialize( $image->tags ) : array();
   if ( empty( $tags ) ) {
      return $terms;
   }

   $first_tag = reset( $tags );

   $term = get_term_by( 'name', $first_tag, $taxonomy );

   if ( ! $term ) {
      $term = wp_insert_term( ucfirst( $first_tag ), $taxonomy );
   }

   $terms[] = $term['term_id'];

   return $terms;
}, 10, 4 );
```

When the code is triggered I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/tds_functionalty_plugin/tds_functionality_plugin.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): {closure}(Array, Object(stdClass), 497, 'category') #1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/instagrate-pro/includes/class-controller.php(696): apply_filters('igp_image_post_...', Array, Object(stdClass), 497, 'category') #3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/instagrate-pro/includes/class-controller.php(1109): Instagrate_Pro_Controller->post_taxonomy(Object(stdClass)) #4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/instagrate-pro/includes/class-controller.php(1407): Instagrate_Pro_Controller->each(3, 8) #5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/instagrate-pro/includes/class-controller.php(115): Instagrate_Pro_Controller->post_account(108, 'constant', '') #6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/instagrate-pro/includes/class-controller.php(72): in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/tds_functionalty_plugin/tds_functionality_plugin.php on line 29

I’m not savvy on arrays and the example code above is from the plugin developer so I believe it to be workable except for some problem in the code that is probably simple to see for the experienced eye.

If anyone could take a look and point me in the right direction toward solving this I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: It's telling you the error is on line 29. What's on that line? I'm guessing this `$terms[] = $term['term_id'];
`

Comment: That is correct.